# What is the nature of the creature living in the ruins of Bethmora?

Tags: plot-explanation, character, hellboy-ii-golden-army

Near the end of [*Hellboy II: The Golden Army*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0411477/), when the team reaches the ruins of *Bethmora*, *Liz* and *Hellboy* are led by some lone goblin into a chamber where they meet some other creature who lives there, depicted here:

[image]

This creature seems to be somehow all-knowing or at least knows about *Liz* and *Hellboy*'s true name and fate and makes prophecies about the future (and says it waited for *Hellboy* for a long time). It is also able to magically heal *Hellboy* from the serious injury he received from *Nuada*, with no effort from one second to the other. All in all it seems quite observant and indifferent to the world's actual fate.

While there is no doubt that this movie is full of weird and mysterious creatures, this one with its somehow decayed yet majestic and elegant appearance and its rather strange powers and mysterious aura was kind of fascinating, especially when found at such a desolate place. **So is there any further information what this creature is all about? What are its background and motives and what does it do alone in the lost ruins of *Bethmora*?**

(If I haven't missed something and it isn't explained any further in the movie, maybe the comics on which the movie are based can shed some light on it or there is some background information from the writers of the comics/movie. But maybe it is never explained any further and it is intended to be unkown and mysterious.)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

She is [Angel of Death](http://hellboy.wikia.com/wiki/Angel_of_Death).

> Jones explained his portrayal, "The script refers to the angel as a
>   her and that's what I do. I think she has feminine qualities, but
>   she's not totally a woman either. And that's okay. I like characters
>   that keep you guessing (Source: [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hellboy_II%3a_The_Golden_Army))

She is just one of the made for movie character and kept to make a guessing  game around viewers or as an open end for sequel.